# UITableView not filling the bottom on the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, swift2

So I have looked at some examples and a blog tutorial already. But the problem with my TableView is it is not filling the bottom of the screen. In the view I have the tableview filling the bottom of the screen. Here is the layout of my storyboard:

[image]

Now here is what it looks like when I run it:[image]

How can I extend the tableviewcells to the bottom of the screen?
Thanks for the help and your time.

Comment: There are no constraints in your storyboard scene. Did you disable auto layout?

Comment: No that isn't it because I have populated the list with enough items to reach the bottom but instead it scrolls to see items not shown.

Comment: No, I am using autolayout

Comment: No, it does not reach the bottom

Comment: Please post a picture of your Storyboard (with the table view selected so we can see what you did) (and the inspector selected, so we can see constraints).

Comment: I don't have any constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out initially I wanted a scroll view on the whole view, so it was also in the space of the tableview which would autoresize the tableview. So I just had to uncheck *Autoresize Subview* and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In interface builder when you have your ViewController selected try unchecking "Adjust Scroll View Insets" parameter.

Comment: I am not seeing that anywhere on the scrollview

Comment: Must have viewcontroller layer selected, not scroll view.